# Centering dots in ggplot on faceted boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet-wrap

I am using facet wrap in ggplot to create boxplots. I am using the fill commend to further break up the data by color. Using other stackoverflow help, I've been able to add points on top of those boxplots. I am now trying to center those dots on each boxplot.  As you can see in the screenshot, the dots are actually centered around the variable "salt" on the x axis, instead of being centered on their respective boxplot. Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Thanks so much for your help!

[image: facetted box and whisker plot with points]

My code:

```r
I<-ggplot(IntTrt72, aes(x=salt, y=rel_diff, fill = stage))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.1) + theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', binwidth = .05,
               color = NA,position = position_dodge())

I<-I+scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5445b1", "#749dae", "#f3c483"))+ theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")
I<- I+facet_wrap(treatmenthours~temp)
I<- I + geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "grey60")
I<- I + scale_y_continuous( breaks=c(-1.0, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25), limits=c(-1.0, 0.3))
I
```

FYI, I am an R beginner.

Comment: It kind of looks like the dotplots are being "dodged" more than the boxplots. Maybe try to set the dodging width inside `position_dodge()` in the dotplot layer, like `position_dodge(width = .75)`? That being said, it'll be much easier for folks to help you if you provide a small example of your dataset so folks can run your code. :) See ideas on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much for your help.                                                     For other's reference, that code now looks like this:                                              I<-ggplot(IntTrt72, aes(x=salt, y=rel_diff, fill = stage))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.1) + theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', binwidth = .05,
               color = NA, position = position_dodge(width = .75))

Thank you, R2evans!